# Alternative to System.exit(1) in Java to pass veracode scan

Tags: java, veracode, system.exit

J2EE Bad Practices: Use of System.exit()

VeraCode scan is showing the above security flaw. Vera Code is pointing to the places where System.exit used other than main() method.

Purpose of the System.exit(1) is to exit the system if the connection is invalid while executing the batch jobs.

What is the alternative to System.exit(1) in order to pass the Vera Code scan.

Comment: Does your application start from a `main()` method?

Comment: check Gio answer here:[Alternatives to System.exit(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790/alternatives-to-system-exit1)

Answer (score 2):

VeraCode scan is showing that because it's set to scan for J2EE - but if you have a main() method, then you're not in an J2EE environment and calling `System.exit()` is OK.